# Build Action bug in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.9.2 DotNet 5.0 (Core console app)

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Found an issue with Visual Studio 2019 where it's impossible to select a Build Action on any static file created. No matter what Build Action is selected, the error "Property value is not valid" message is displayed every time.

```
An error has occurred while saving the edited properties listed below:
    Build Action
One or more values are invalid. User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED))
```

Is there a known workaround for this? I'm running DotNet 5.0 and it's a very simple console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a reboot of Visual Studio solved the problem. Go figure.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.